# Tkinter GUI automatically closing despite using similar structure to another user

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24849265/how-do-i-create-an-automatically-updating-gui-using-tkinter) question as a reference for how to structure a Tkinter class, but when I run the program and answer the pop-up dialog I create, the root window automatically closes.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import simpledialog as sd 
from datetime import datetime, date
import time
import pyowm as owm

# access API key
owm = foo
COUNTRY = 'US'

class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        # create window and set size
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("Weatherman")
        self.root.geometry('700x200')

        # get location
        self.location = sd.askstring("Input","What's your location? Format as City, Country",parent=self.root)
        self.location.strip()

        # get date and time 
        current_date = StringVar()
        current_date.set(date.today)

        # debug label to check variable
        self.test_label = Label(self.root,text=current_date.get())
        self.test_label.pack()

def main():
    app = App()
    app.mainloop

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Read [Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you should only have one instance of `tk.Tk()` running at any one time.
You need to decide whether you want your app to inherit from `tk.Tk`, or if it will be composed of a root instance of `tk.Tk()`...

Further, asking for user input from the `__init__` method is somewhat an anti-pattern. I refactored this in a separate function.

Last, the self-actuating powers of `tk.Stringvar` are fully expressed when you assign it to a widget `textvariable`.

The following example of uses inheritance from `tk.Tk`:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog
from datetime import date


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, location=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Weatherman")
        self.geometry('700x200')
        current_date = tk.StringVar()
        current_date.set(str(date.today()))
        self.location = None

        self.test_label = tk.Label(self, textvariable=current_date)
        self.test_label.pack()


def get_location(app):
    location = tk.simpledialog.askstring("Input","What's your location? Format as City, Country")
    return location.strip()


def main():
    app = App()
    app.location = get_location(app)
    app.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```